# intellij idea how to use project A as library for project B

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structure

I want to use classes and interfaces from project A in project B. I tried to figure out how libraries, modules and maven work. But I can't find a useful tutorial. I don't want to just copy everything.

Comment: google 'MAVEN', create a maven project, and add the first project as a dependency

Comment: When you say module do you mean java 9 module

Comment: @Stultuske How I already said, I tried to to find out how Maven works, and I don't only want to be able to add dependencies when I create a new project. That would mean that I have to create a new project every time I want to change a dependency. That would be highly inefficient and unprofessional.

Comment: @NomanKhan I mean the modules tab under project structure

Comment: @jackjuni that's nonsense. after you add/remove a dependency, all you need to do is rebuild your project. If you have dependencies needed for all your projects, you can create a parent project, and build your new projects on top of that.

Answer (score 1):

If both of your projects are **maven** based, then the best approach is building the '*A*' project artifact and add it as a dependency to project '*B*' just like any other maven dependency.

If you want to edit both projects at the same time then you can import project '*A*' as a maven module to the new project.

Just pay attention to rebuild the former artifact in case of any changes to be effective in the new project.